# I want to show an image has been selected by changing the picture. How would I do this?

Tags: javascript

If I make an image into a button, how do I make it so that when I select this button, the image changes, allowing the user to know it has been selected?

Comment: Have you tried adding function to `onclick` of Image Button?

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```
<img src="image1.png" 
  onclick="if(this.src=='image1.png') this.src='image2.png'; 
           else this.src='image1.png';" 
/>
```